# PostgreSQL - aggregate functions are not allowed in JOIN conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to fix this error

Error in query: ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in JOIN conditions

this my query

```
SELECT *
FROM "downloads" dl 
   inner join access_logs l 
    on dl.id=l.download_id 
      and dl.file_id=l.file_id 
      and dl.site_id=l.site_id 
      and sum(l.body_bytes_Sent)>dl.filesize
```

I want the list of all files downloaded completely.

```
sum(body_bytes_Sent)>=filesize
```

Comment: Aggregate in CTE or subquery then join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are assuming that somehow SQL will know that it should sum somthing - but is has not received any instructions on how to perform the aggregation which requires a `group by` clause. So, form a complete query and then join it as a "derived table" like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM downloads dl 
inner join (
  SELECT download_id, file_id, site_id, sum(l.body_bytes_Sent) AS sum_sent
  FROM access_logs 
  GROUP BY download_id, file_id, site_id
    ) AS l 
      on dl.id=l.download_id 
      and dl.file_id=l.file_id 
      and dl.site_id=l.site_id 
      and L.sum_Sent > dl.filesize
```

As there are no details to hand on the data model, or sample data to inspect, the query above may still require refinement.